# How can I show that $\ln(1+x)=x+o(x)$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

How can show that $\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$ using $\exp^{\log x}=x$ and $\exp^t=1+t +o(t)$

I tried to express
$1+t=\exp^{\log(1+t)}=1+\log(1+t)+o(\log(1+t))$

But then I am stuck and do not know how to proceed? How can I finish the proof?

Comment: Do you know Taylor's formula?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1+o(1)$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$. By definition, this limit is $\ln^\prime1=\tfrac11=1$.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's theorem, $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+\dots=x+\mathcal o(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^t = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac {t}{n})^n$

and if we multiply this out (treating $n$ as a finite number).

$1 +n\frac {t}{n} + \frac {n(n-1)}{2} \frac {t^2}{n^2} + \cdots$

And let $n$ go to infinity.

As for $\ln (1+t).$

You can use Taylor's theorem (works for $e^t$, too.)

$f(t) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac {1}{2} f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2$

or you can get a little tricky.

$f(x) = \ln (1+x)\\
f'(x) = \frac {1}{1+x}$

Remember, the sum of a geometric series $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac {1}{1-r}$

Then
$f'(x) = \frac {1}{1+x} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n$

Integrate both sides.

$f(x) = \int_{0}^x f(x)\ dx = f(0) + \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-x)}{n+1}^{n+1} = x - \frac {x}{2} + \cdots$